# Python 3: ошибка в библиотеке mpmath?

Tags: python

В Python 3 (anaconda) запускаю код:

```
from mpmath import *

mp.dps = 256
mp.mpf(45742139854791163576.0)
```

результат:

```
mpf('45742139854791163904.0')
```

последние 3 цифры неправильные.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `45742139854791163576.0` - это вещественный литерал. Сперва питон переводит его во `float`, теряет точность, затем передаёт в mpmath. Используйте строку: `mp.mpf('45742139854791163576.0')`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.